# SSRS difference between Columns

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS report with two row group and one Column Group, the Sample Data Result is like "

```
SKU    Root Product Title     3 days    6 days
610121     Heart Rate Monitor     5         15
```

I wanna add a column to find out the difference between 3 days and 6 days which will be looked like :

```
  SKU      Root Product Title     3 days    6 days   difference
610121     Heart Rate Monitor     5         15         -10
```

The 3 days and 6 days belong to same column group, Can anyone please help me with this~~ Much Appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

You need an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) in a new column. Take these steps:

1. Right-click the "6 days" column header.
2. Choose "Add column" within the group (to the right).
3. Enter your header manually.
4. Right-click the cell and choose "Expression..."
5. Set the expression to something like

   `=Fields!ThreeDays.Value - Fields!SixDays.Value`

   (or whatever you have to represent the 3 and 6 day values)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the report items themselves in your expression. First you need to find the "names" of the textboxes that you have for these.

Let's say the '3 days' column is called 'Textbox14' and the '6 days' column is called 'Textbox15', your expression would be:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox14.Value - ReportItems!Textbox15.Value
```

This is especially useful if the two columns are complex expressions and don't just display a field from the dataset. Now you don't have to maintain the expression in two places.